# How do I let SWIG know about my C++ float * class variables?

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to make a C# wrapper for C++ code similar to the following:

```
class blah {
  ...
public:
  float *getVarA() { return a; }
private
  float *a;
  ...
}
```

In my interface file, I use the following %apply:

```
%apply float OUTPUT[] { float *getVarA() }
```

This causes the C# wrapper to return a float[], but the wrapper function doesn't know what float *a is.  This causes a plethora of the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'float[]' to 'System.IntPtr'
```

The wrapper function created:

```
public float[] getVarA() {
  IntPtr cPtr = SpectrumPINVOKE.blah_getVarA(swigCPtr);
  SWIGTYPE_p_float ret = (cPtr == IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_float(cPtr, false);
  return ret;
}
```

When using non-pointer types, such as:

```
class blah {
  ...
public:
  int getVarB() { return b; }
private:
  int b;
  ...
}
```

I get a nice proper

```
public int getVarB() {
  int ret = SpectrumPINVOKE.blah_getVarB(swigCPtr);
  return ret;
}
```

I've read the 2.0 Documentation more than I'd like, but I'm missing something somewhere and I can't find it right now.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this can work as stated, as the wrapper function has no way of knowing how many elements are in the array and therefore can't allocate the appropriate size to return. Have you tried making the C function return a fixed size array (and remove the %apply)? Alternatively you could return a vector and include std_vector.i.

Comment: Another option is to return a pointer and a size as arguments. As @HunterGuy2 mentions, there is no way SWIG can know the size of the array to return

Comment: Use a typemap, see also [How do I process string arrays with swig and C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512549/how-do-i-process-string-arrays-with-swig-and-c)