# How do I process string arrays with swig and C#?

Tags: c#, swig

My C++ class has a method called `init`:

```
int init(int argc, char **argv)
```

Also, I have a callback:

```
void callback(int num, char **str)
```

My problem is that Swig generates a strange class `SWIGTYPE_p_p_char.cs`, and no `string[]` as I expected.
Please, advice.

Answer (score 3):

SWIG has some typemaps for passing arrays to functions, in arrays_csharp.i. There isn't one for `char *INPUT[]` however but we can adapt the typemaps to do what you want:

```
%module test

%include <arrays_csharp.i>

CSHARP_ARRAYS(char *, string)
%typemap(imtype, inattributes="[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.LPStr)]") char *INPUT[] "string[]"

%apply char *INPUT[]  { char **argv }

int foo(int argc, char **argv);
```

This uses the SWIG macro CSHARP_ARRAYS to produce the typedefs for an array of `string`s, but then replaces the imtype so we can give our own marshaling information.

I think that should be sufficient. If you want you can add an overload to the generated module with:

```
%pragma(csharp) modulecode = %{
  public static int foo(string[] argv) {
    return foo(argv.Length, argv);
  }
%}
```

Note: Test this carefully - I've never written a C# program in my life (but have written lots of SWIG+JNI). I found the [marshaling information on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/1d743627-6c4b-4eaf-9008-500f25e58617) but haven't tested any of this beyond checking that the output from SWIG looks sane. This seems to match [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7644330/168175), with the addition of [`SizeParamIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).